# Splitting a String C++

Tags: c++, parsing

I am entering this type of input from command line :

`mynameis "jason roger"`

I want to have **mynameis** and **jason roger** in two different strings.
But I even failed in printing the input.
When I use this

```
  string command;

  cin>>command
  cout<<command<<endl;
```

I get this

```
mynameis
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `>>` operator reads from the input stream (`cin`, here) until it hits a whitespace character. You might want to look at the [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) function instead, but you would need to split your string manually.

Comment: Cool Jason replied jason !

Comment: this question could very well be about json

Comment: He could also do a looped getline using a space as the delimiter.  He'd probably want to use a vector to make it work with input of arbitrary length.

Answer (score 3):

you should use `getline` to get input which includes whilte-spaces. 
in this way:

```
 getline(cin, str); // here str is string
```